# $\cos \tau$ need to write in a different way

Tags: formatting, equations

```
$$\frac{S \epsilon  \text{Cos}[\tau ]}{\sqrt{\lambda }}+\frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2 (-3+\text{Cos}[2 \tau ])}{6 \lambda }+\epsilon ^3 \left(\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda +Z \left(\frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}-\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}+\frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}-\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6}+\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \text{Cos}[\tau ]}{\lambda ^{5/2}}+\frac{S^3 \left(4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda \right) \text{Cos}[3 \tau ]}{72 \lambda ^{3/2}}\right)$$
```

I have copied this from Mathematica as tex file. But the problem is  I need to write the $\cos[x]$ as $\cos x$.
How can I do it?[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you need to change `\text{Cos}[...]` into `\cos ...`

Comment: You should look for a find and replace function provided by your text editor.

Comment: I have changed \text{Cos}[...] into \cos ... but it's not woking. :-(

Comment: Is there an error message coming up or is it that you don't like the spacing in the output between cos and tau? try \cos\!\tau

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following?

I've replaced the `\text{Cos}` (my eyes!) by `\cos`.

You can use a `gathered` environment to break the equation in multiple, centered lines.

Make sure that each line containing an opening `\left...` also contains a closing `\right...`.

Also, use `\[` and `\]` to open and close an unnumbered displayed equation, not `$$`; see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{S \epsilon  \cos \tau}{\sqrt{\lambda }}
+ \frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2 (-3+\cos 2 \tau)}{6 \lambda }\\
+ \epsilon ^3 \left(\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda
+ Z \left(\frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}-\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}
+ \frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}-\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6}
+ \frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \cos \tau}{\lambda ^{5/2}}\right.\\
\left.+\frac{S^3 \left(4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda \right) \cos 3 \tau}{72 \lambda ^{3/2}}\right)
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```